# How to remove door from bathroom cabinet

Tags: bathroom, mirror

Hoping to get some help with this bathroom wall cabinet... How am I supposed to remove the door? It has a "pin", with a corresponding hole above, but the pin head is completely flat so I cannot "unscrew" it. Is there a trick?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6iiv.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivWY5.jpg]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8lCJ.jpg]

Comment: Have you tried pushing something down the hole to push the pin down?

Comment: I did but perhaps not with a ton of strength. A bit afraid of damaging the entire cabinet or making it fall. It also doesn't look like the pin has anywhere to go down inside the door.

Comment: If it is a spring pin, it might be struck.  Light tapping on the tool might loosen it.  Double check that the pin is a flat top with a bright light.

Comment: I think you're right. I was able to partially push the pin down from the top. However, there are some washers around the pin, so I don't think I can fully push it to remove it... oh well.

Comment: try lifting the door

Comment: @jsotola - it looks like there's a whole 1-2mm of play at the top. Unlikely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check it doesn't need a matching bottom pin pushing up first - that would let gravity keep it all in place the rest of the time, until you need it out. The top pin might then not need any moving at all, all done from underneath, swing out & drop away.

Alternatively - it might be designed in such a way as you have to remove either top or base panel. The top has some pretty obvious screw-holes.

Comment: Perfect! Removing top worked and was super simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you open the door there should be 2 hinges on the inside with. Approximately 3 screws on each . Unscrew those and door comes off.

Comment: No hinge on the inside, unfortunately. The door just pivots around that pin.

Comment: @ManknowsBest -  I think you're looking at the big, obvious hinges, not the actual door pin the OP is asking about. The big obvious hinges look like they're for the side mirrors, not the door.

Comment: Frankly, removing a hinge isn't necessarily the easiest way to pull a door, but it'll certainly work.